# How to fix this line of code that encounters "cannot assign to function call" error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I encounter a "cannot assign to function call" error when running this line:

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'input' : np.random.randint(0, 10, 100), 'output' : np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)})
df_temp.loc[(df_temp['input'] > 4) & (df_temp['output'] == 4), df_temp['output'].shift()] = -1
```

What I'm trying to do is to assign value `-1` to the shifted position of column `output` based on the conditions of columns `input > 4` and `output == 4`

Comment: The accessor expects `DataFrame.loc[<rows>, <columns>]`, but you provided `DataFrame.loc[<rows>, <more rows>]`

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest how to fix it?

Comment: I generate a separate shift column, which works but there are extra steps. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: what defines efficient in your case? fewer lines of code? shorter run time?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'input' : np.random.randint(0, 10, 100), 'output' : np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)})
first_val = df_temp.loc[df_temp.index[0], 'output']
df_temp.loc[(df_temp['input'] > 4) & (df_temp['output'] == 4), 'output'] = -1
df_temp.loc[df_temp.index[0], 'output'] = first_val
```

It's about `.loc[index_filter, col_filter]` `col_filter` is not `pd.Series` it's either single string to indicate single column, or list of strings to indicate multiple columns.

If you want to emulate shift behaviour, and at the same time use Boolean-indexing - just preserve on the side whatever shift you want, overwrite everything, then replace back the part, which you want to preserve by shift